# two different realization of one type

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Im having trouble solving this problem:

> Let $M$ be a saturated structure of cardinality $\kappa$. Let $A\subseteq |M|$ with $|A|<\kappa$. Then there is a type $p\in S_1(A)$ with two different realizations.

I have tried to assume towards contradiction that all types in $S_1(A)$ have only one realization. and from there to conclude that for any $a\in|M|$ we get that $tp(a/A)$  are all the possible types there are in $S_1(A)$ and from there to isolate enough types to get a contradiction to the compactness of $S_1(A)$ as a topological space. but i didn't manage to continue to show this.

I will be happy to get some help 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by showing that for any type $p(x)\in S_1(A)$, if $p$ has exactly one realization in $M$, then there is some formula $\varphi(x)\in p$ such that $T\models \exists ! x\, \varphi(x)$. Then use compactness to show that there's a type which avoids all such formulas $\varphi$.

Your idea involving isolated types will also work ($\varphi$ isolates $p$ above), but you would have to break into cases, since it's possible that every type over $A$ is isolated. (But only if $A$ is finite and $T$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical! Then use the pigeonhole principal to find that one of the finitely many types over $A$ is realized many times.)

Comment: Hi, so i though i got this now, but not actually. Im am trying to find such $\varphi$ bay taking for every $b\in |M|$ $\psi _b \in p$ such that (assuming $a$ is realizing $p$ in $M$) we have $M\vDash \psi _b (a)$ and $M\vDash \neg \psi _b (b)$ and then i try to show that $\{\neg \psi_b : b\in M \}$ is inconsistent and then take a finite minimal set of inconsistent formulas from that set and take the conjunction as $\varphi$ but i don't see why it's inconsistent... maybe it isn't the right way?

Comment: That could work, but I think the set you want to show is inconsistent is $\{\psi_ b(x) \mid b\neq a\} \cup \{x \neq a\}$.

Comment: The argument I had in mind went like this: $p(x)$ has only one realization in $M$, so $p(x)\cup p(y) \cup \{x\neq y\}$ is inconsistent, since $M$ is saturated. So by compactness...